# Primefaces PF function

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

OK, I use JSF with Primefaces Glasfish 5.X + server. I want to know how it works exactly the PF function as I need to corroborate or a widget is not visible in the view. My idea was

```
<h:form>
         <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+shift+s" handler="notify()"/>
</h:form>
            <h:outputScript>
                function notify(){
                    if(PF('bar').is(':visible')){
                        PF('bar').hide();
                    }
                    else{
                        PF('bar').show()
                    }
                }
            </h:outputScript>
```

But, tada : Google Chrome said "Uncaught TypeError: PF(...).is is not a function".

My existential question is: where is the documentaciond PF function ? or at least would solve this problem. Thanks people.

Comment: Here is some guide http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/ and you can't use any jQuery function on `PF('id')`, only those specified in PrimeFaces User's Guide for given component. If you want to convert `PF(id)` object to jQuery object use `PF('id').getJQ()` (it's also said in the link).

Comment: You were right! @Geinmachi for president. I solved the console showing "PF ( 'bar' ) " . And it has implemented the " toggle " method.

Comment: Where to download GlassFish 5.x? I want to use that version. I see [GlassFish 4.1](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html) as the currently available latest version.

Comment: Mmmm was Primefaces 5.X. I was drunk when asked. My apologies to the families affected .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pf function select a widget in a widget array.

if you check the source code of primefaces.js (or something like that ):

```
PF = function(d) {
    var c = b.widgets[d];
    if (!c) {
        b.error("Widget for var '" + d + "' not available!")
    }
    return c
};
```

b seems to contain a lot of stuff including an array of widgets.

you can open the page containing the javascript by opening a page where you have primefaces included and in the head there will be something similar to this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/yourNameSpace/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2"></script>
```

then you can right clip and open it but the file won't contain any space etc to be less heavy. Just copy everything (ctrl+a then ctrl+c) go to eclipse paste it and format it (ctrl + shift +f).